# How to write JS which working on single page of react router at project created create-react-app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm woking on a single page react project. I wanna hide header at one of my page(products page). I write code below for this at my slide-down component which is placed the page i wanna hide header. But when i load the products page the code working on other pages too. My slide-down component placed at product page and i'am encountering this error at other pages: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null*

There is the gif about the problem:
imgur link: https://imgur.com/YP43PbO
direct link: https://i.imgur.com/YP43PbO.gifv

```js
useEffect(() => {
        let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
        window.onscroll = function() {
            let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
            let headerH = document.getElementById("header").clientHeight
            if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
                document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
                document.getElementById("slide-down").style.top = `${headerH}px`;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("header").style.top = `-${headerH}px`;
                document.getElementById("slide-down").style.top = "0";
            }
            prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute your codes only when that id is exist.

Two ways come to my mind. The first one is to use "try catch" statement. And the other one is to check if the id is exist before executing those commands.

> ***Note that I agree with the second solution***

### Solution one (try and catch):

```
useEffect(() => {
  let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  window.onscroll = function () {
    try {
      let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      let headerH = document.getElementById("header").clientHeight
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
        document.getElementById("slide-down").style.top = `${headerH}px`;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = `-${headerH}px`;
        document.getElementById("slide-down").style.top = "0";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    } catch (e) {
      //do nothing or log "e" to console ( console.log(e) )
    }
  }
})
```

> Just remember to create a variable for `document.getElementById("header")` and `document.getElementById("slide-down")` instead of repeating it
> several times (just like I did in the second solution). Doing so will
> improve the performance of your application

### Solution two (Check if id exist):

```
useEffect(() => {
  let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  let header = getElementById("header"),
    slide_down = getElementById("slide-down");
  if (header && slide_down) {
    window.onscroll = function () {
      let currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      let headerH = header.clientHeight
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        header.style.top = "0";
        slide_down.style.top = `${headerH}px`;
      } else {
        header.style.top = `-${headerH}px`;
        slide_down.style.top = "0";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Solution two (Check if id exist) works very well. Thank you for your help <3 I am appreciative.